# Converting (Polyline Data) JSON to GeoDataFrame using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, json, geodataframe

I have this particular [json](https://tataruang.jakarta.go.id/server/rest/services/DCKTRP/PETA_OPS_UTM_JAKARTA_ITBX2/FeatureServer/0/1?f=pjson) and **I want to make the JSON into a GeoDataFrame (with geometry and its attributes);** How to set the geometry and attributes to a geodataframe?

---

I have tried using `geopandas.read_file()` and it returned an error: "*expected string or bytes-like object*"; 

I also tried `geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_features()` but it returns this table (which is the problem): 

[image: wrong form of geodataframe]

I want it to look like something like this (a geometry column, and the other attribute columns):

[image: the right geodataframe]

I am aware of Esri's ArcGIS API for Python but, in this case, I can't use ArcGIS API or ArcPy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoPandas uses Shapely to define geometry. so Using shapely we can define a function to grab the json, cleans it, and convert the geometry into a shapely object. Here's how to convert the json into a GeoDataFrame:
with link = [web service](https://tataruang.jakarta.go.id/server/rest/services/DCKTRP/PETA_OPS_UTM_JAKARTA_ITBX2/FeatureServer/0/), then;

```
# function "get_line" should retrieve the JSON and returns a GeoDataFrame
# if it's a polygon, then the import shapely must be "Polygon" and ...
# ... the ['paths'] must be ['rings']

def get_line(base_link, objid):
    from shapely.geometry import LineString
    iterator=objid
    link=base_link + "/" + str(objid) + "?f=pjson"
    print(link)
    js = r.get(link, verify=False).json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(js['feature']['attributes'], index=[0])
    df['geom']=LineString(js['feature']['geometry']['paths'][0])
    crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs).set_geometry(df['geom'])
    return gdf

link = "insert link to web service, here"
get_line(link,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing *r* in *r.get* is the *requests* library and its return a json object? If so, you can just convert your request to a string and use *read_file* into a GeoDataFrame.

```
url = "https://..."
gdf = gpd.read_file(r.get(url).text)
```

Comment: This answer even makes the geodataframe CRS-aware!