# How can I use GeoPandas to read a string containing GeoJSON content into a GeoDataFrame?

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas

Suppose I have a string that contains raw unparsed GeoJSON data. For example:

```py
geojson_str = '''{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 1, "test": "a" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 3.0, 7.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 2, "test": "b" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 5.0, 5.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 3, "test": "c" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 7.0, 3.0 ] } }
]
}
'''
```

How can I read the data above into a GeoDataFrame?

Comment: I know this seems like a small silly post, but I didn't find this info being stated anywhere else, so I just wanted to document it here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can load that string into a `GeoDataFrame` using the `read_file` method:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.read_file(geojson_str, driver='GeoJSON')
```

In the code above, `gdf` is a CRS-aware GeoDataFrame that you can manipulate however you want.

### Credit

Special credit to [@tynowell](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/157347/tynowell) for highlighting that this is possible in [an unrelated thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/371869/123828).