# Convert from data to GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, geodataframe

I have this code and I need convert this information to GeoDataFrame. How can I do this?

```
import requests

url = 'https://gis.arlingtonva.us/arlgis/rest/services/public/Parking/MapServer/2/query'

params = {
    'where': '1=1',
    'outFields': '*',
    'returnGeometry': 'true',
    'f': 'geojson'
}

response = requests.get(url, params)
assert response.status_code==200
data = response.json()
```

[image]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/420164/2856